# A simple augmented reality application in C#

Tags: c#, augmented-reality

I would like to start a personal project that will give me a lot of new concept to learn and understand.

After some thought, I figured that an Augmented Reality related project will be the most beneficial for me because of the following reasons:

- I haven't tried interfacing a program with a live video/camera feed
- I haven't done any "image processing" project
- I haven't done any "graphics rendering" ever

With that said, you can assume that I will totally suck at AR. So I'm here to ask for some advice regarding the best way to go through this.

1. st milestone project that I am thinking of is to take a cheap webcam and read some Data Matrix using C#.
2. nd milestone project will render some text-overlay on the feed when presented with a certain Data Matrix.
3. rd milestone project will actually render some 3D shapes.

I've searched all-around and found some nice yet advanced materials for AR:

http://sites.google.com/site/augmentedrealitytestingsite/

http://soldeveloper.com/

http://www.mperfect.net/wpfAugReal/

So I came here to ask the following:

In order to start Milestone 1, can you give some materials that I can study? I prefer online materials.

Thanks!

Edit: Removed "subjective" question.

Comment: Vote to Close: Anytime a core question starts with "Do you think...", I feel the question is likely subjective and argumentative. Questions on this site should be focused with the ability to clearly answer them. "Do you think..." questions are, therefore, subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*1. Do you think my milestone is reasonable given my "deficiencies"?*

Sorry, but that's really impossible for us to answer. We don't know your dedication, previous background in programming, your amount of talent or time, ...

*2. In order to start Milestone 1, can you give some materials that I can study? I prefer online materials.*

I'd start with implementing something with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (there are quite some tutorials floating around the net). This should make attaining your further goals a lot more realistic (not reinventing the wheel).

There are different .NET bindings around, e.g. [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [OpenCVdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/) or ... (I'm in no position to comment on the quality of these bindings).

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I would recommend you start with [GoblinXNA](http://goblinxna.codeplex.com) . It's pretty straightforward, allows you to create an environment based on a scene graph model and has somewhat robust documentation. More importantly, it's not necessary to go very low-level with it. It incorporates OpenCV and some marker-tracking libraries.

Best of all, it's free and open source.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for it, and I still prefer it for others out there for entry to mid-size level projects.